# How to get subscription id from the VM in AZURE

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Is there a way to get the subscription id from the running (LINUX)VM instance in AZURE?

Can WALinuxAgent read the subscription ID from the internal server ?

Answer (score 7):

This can be achieved using the [Azure Instance Metadata Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/instance-metadata-service). Calling this service from your VM will return a JSON with SubscriptionId among other useful data. Sample Microsoft bash script for calling the metadata service (with updated version in the request):

```
sudo apt-get install curl
sudo apt-get install jq
curl -H Metadata:True "http://169.254.169.254/metadata/instance?api-version=2017-08-01&format=json" | jq .
```

See "Response" section in provided link for sample response, with subscriptionId.

Answer (score 0):

You can use powershell to achieve this.
First of all.
What kind of VM deployment model?

**ARM**

In this case it very simple.

```
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $vmName
$vm.Id
```

You'll see - "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/..."

**Classic**

If you know resource group VM was deployed to, use following:

```
$resource = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType Microsoft.ClassicCompute/virtualMachines -Name $vmName
$resource.ResourceId
```

Same - you"ll see "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/..."

Way to find resourceGroupName, if unknown (in case you write some automative script):

```
$vm = Get-AzureVM | Where {$_.Name -eq $vmName}
$service = Get-AzureService -ServiceName $vm.ServiceName
$service.ExtendedProperties.ResourceGroup
```

Hope it helps

Comment: What is the Linux equivalent of this since Powershell would not be available in Linux? Azure CLI requires login which defeats the purpose of automation